# Create and remove div in jQuery and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

In my website I have different boxes of different artists and a play button on each to load a Spotify player.

I am using to do that this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".playid-"+#{artist.id.to_s}).click(function () {
$(".player-id-"+#{artist.id.to_s}).fadeToggle()
;}
```

Is working fine. However when I click to the second/third... play button the div of the player is created again and again one over another.

What I want is check if the div exist, then hide/destroy/remove and then create the new div of the player so I only have 1 div created at any time.

I have tried with .remove but I don't know the correct way to then create a new div with the same code that is this:

```
%div{:class => 'player player-id-'+artist.id.to_s}
  %iframe{:src => 'https://embed.spotify.com/?uri='+artist.spotify_player_url, :width => "100%", :height => "80px", :frameborder => "0", :allowtransparency => "true", :class => "player_spotify"  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about hide all `player` elements before showing new one?

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $(".playid-"+#{artist.id.to_s}).click(function () {
    $(".player").fadeOut();
    if( $(".player-id-"+#{artist.id.to_s}).is(':hidden') ) {
      $(".player-id-"+#{artist.id.to_s}).fadeIn();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. With that is working fine to create and destroy but when I click to the play button again is loading again the player instead of hide it and I need it like with the .fadeToggle() attribute. If I click to play one time fadeIn but if I click second time to same player is FadeOut.

Comment: Thank you @antyrat I added and answer with the correct code. Very similar to yours! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code if anyone need it. Thank you a lot to antyrat

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$(".playid-"+#{artist.id.to_s}).click(function () {
$(".player").fadeOut();
if(!$(".player-id-"+#{artist.id.to_s}).is(":visible")) {
$(".player-id-"+#{artist.id.to_s}).fadeIn();
}
}
)
;}
);
```